# .gitignore file not ignoring correctly

Tags: git, github

I have a .gitignore file with the following contents.

```
*.o
*.exe
*Debug/*
*.vpb
*.vtg
*.vpwhistu
*.vpwhist
*.vtg
```

After working on a project (modifying a couple of files) in my working directory, If I do

```
git status
```

I get the following output

```
Workspace/playpen/boost/Debug/simple_ls.o
```

Why is this happening despite `*Debug/*` being inside `.gitignore`. Isn't that the whole point of .gitignore.

Answer (score 1):

`.gitignore` only works on files which are not already part of the remote repository.  My guess is that `simple_ls.o` was already being tracked when you added the rule to `.gitignore`.  If you want Git to ignore it, then you first have to remove it from the remote repository via:

```
git rm --cached Workspace/playpen/boost/Debug/simple_ls.o
```

After this, the `.gitignore` pattern will prevent this file from being added to the repository.

Answer (score 0):

Did you modify your .gitignore ? Was this file already tracked ? because it is supposed to ignore .o files too.

for ignoring the debug folder your should modify your rules as :
`**Debug/`

Comment: This should be a comment on the question instead of an answer as it provides no solution to the OPs question.

Comment: of course it is the solution. If the file was previously tracked, it will continue to show modification on that particular file even if a matching rule in a .gitignore is added

Answer (score 0):

Having a `/` in the your pattern (other than as the last character of the pattern) anchors the pattern at the point of the directory hierarchy that contains the `.gitignore` file itself.

This means that `*Debug/*` will ignore anything in directories such as `FooDebug`, `BarDebug` and `Debug` at the same level as `.gitignore`, but not further down the hierarchy. To ignore any directories which have names ending in `Debug`, simply use the pattern:

```
*Debug/
```

The trailing slash tells Git to only match against directories, but this pattern will match at any level of your directory tree.